# Communicating with the PC via USB connection in Android

Tags: android

I'm fairly new to android programming and need some information for a 4th year forensics course project. Basically I am trying to create a suite of tools for live analysis of an android phone. I know how to get the information I need on the phone, but I was wondering if there was a way to communicate that information back to the PC? I want to be able to run a program from a PC, which, when the phone is docked, will allow the user to access information about the phone (ie currently running services/processes, bluetooth/wifi connections, etc). I have a bunch of methods that will run on the phone and get all the information, but I want to be able to call those methods from the PC, execute on the phone, then have the information sent back to the PC to display to the user instead of just displaying it on the phone. This is to leave as small a footprint on the phone as possible. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The ADT eclipse plugin does some of what you are asking.
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html
If you can track down the source for it, you should be able to figure out how to do it.